# App Engine deploy failing with "fatal: unable to access 'https://gopkg.in/yaml.v3/': server certificate verification failed."

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment, certificate

Anyone else getting this issue when deploying Go/Other projects to the App Engine?

Deployment was working fine on Tuesday, Sept 28. I tried to deploy on Friday, Oct 1 (yesterday) and today, but I still got the same error.  It's not a code-related error as the code hasn't changed since the last deployment.

From the log:

> Step #2 - "build": go:
> gopkg.in/yaml.v3@v3.0.0-20200313102051-9f266ea9e77c: git fetch -f
> origin refs/heads/*:refs/heads/* refs/tags/*:refs/tags/* in
> /layers/google.go.gomod/gopath/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/5ea86ba1b933025fb7a7a539058d4acea777e0b3175c573a70130f7ea565323f:
> exit status 128: Step #2 - "build":   fatal: unable to access
> 'https://gopkg.in/yaml.v3/': server certificate verification failed.
> CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none

If I'm reading this right, is there a missing certificate in the App Engine? But then, I'm not sure what certificate it needs since I never had to provide one before. Maybe if I delete the certificate file, App Engine will recreate it?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12):

Experienced the certificate error too.

Assuming you are using the official golang image, to fix the certificate issue, you need to update `ca-certificates` and `libgnutls30` packages.

```
RUN apt update && apt install ca-certificates libgnutls30 -y
```

Comment: In Google's PaaS environment (App Engine Standard) you don't have direct access to the build environment. You may be able to run certain scripts during the build triggers but it wasn't apparent how I would do that.  After submitting the issue to the Google issue tracker, it was fixed by Google.  I changed the runtime back to go111 and the application deployed without issue. Migration to go115 is on our roadmap and it's nice that I don't have to do that right now.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue is Travis CI build.

I changed the build image to ubuntu 20.04 (from 16.04)
and update package ca-certificates

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates
```

Comment: Under the hood, App Engine Standard environment is Debian. So, I tried what I think is the Debian equivalent "update-ca-certificates" but the issue persists. I also tried: 

git config --global http.sslVerify false
export GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=1

I have a feeling that the vm instance that these commands are executing in is not the same the google tools use to deploy. 

App Engine standard environment is a PaaS environment and -- in theory -- you wouldn't have to worry about these kind of settings since the environment handles these kind of tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Solved ... mostly

This solution is for those running on App Engine Standard environment using Go 1.11

change your runtime in app.yaml to

```
runtime: go115
```

and change your go version in go.mod file:

```
module myapp

go 1.11
```

This will allow you to deploy your application. In my case, there were other changes I had to make to the app.yaml. For example, I had to add

```
app_engine_apis: true
```

I have my app deployed now but not completely running.  I'll post relevant fixes here if I discover anything else. Hope this helps those that run into this issue.

Comment: When did Google add this `app_engine_apis` flag? We've been stuck on 1.11 for ages. Does the devappserver still work with that flag?

Comment: Henry, this has been released as a preview feature in [1] to use App Engine bundled service for 2nd generation runtimes. 
[1]https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go111/config/appref#runtime_and_app_elements

Answer (score 0):

To sum it all up -- it was an issue on the App Engine side. Other users experienced the same problem and the Google team resolved the issue.

For reference I've posted the issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/201753230

For my project, I reverted the "runtime: go115" changes to go111 (also removed app_engine_apis from app.yaml) and the application deployed as normal.